# How to store a huge hash table in RAM and share it between different applications?

Tags: hashtable, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

The data contains information like billions of ID-scores pairs. To quickly access these paired information, I plan to use the hash-table container since its time complexity of search is O(1). Considering the the raw data is around 80G, I don't want to load the data into RAM every time when I need to run search application. What I want to do is to generate the hash-table once and then store it in RAM with persistence of filesystem lifetime (the expense of RAM is not a criteria), and search it with different applications.

Based on my limited understanding, I could use "Memory Mapped Files" (boost C++ libraries). But I have questions:

1) Is it possible to keep the hash-table data structure when write it to the mapped file?
2) How much time it will cost to map the existed file to RAM?

Any answers/comments/suggestions are most welcomed!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes. The file is just bytes, just like memory.

2) Creating the mapping will be effectively instantaneous. Node that you won't be able to map all of it contiguously at once except on a 64-bit OS. Of course, if the file cache can't hold the portion of the map you're using, it will have to be read from disk.

How big are IDs? How big are pairs? How much locality of reference do you have? (Are there heavily-used pair and lightly used pairs?) How often will you be searching for pairs that aren't present? Is the data read-mostly? There may be better ways to do it. I'd strongly suggest starting with a broader question to make sure you're not stuck on a sub-optimal path.

Comment: There are ~2 billion IDs (36 characters), each ID's value contains one short int and one unsigned int. Since each ID's value is not a single information, there maybe an extra step to parse the needed information. All IDs have equal chance to be queried, so all pairs are evenly used. There are maybe < 1/3 chance to search a ID that is not listed in the table. Once the data is generated, it will be fixed, no write/insert/appended/edit. David, appreciate your help.

Comment: Consider [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/)'s B+ tree implementation.

Comment: The RAM is >> 80G and the OS could be 64bit if needed.